# From matrix column subtract corresponding vector value

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

I have a matrix 'x' and a row vector 'v'; the number of elements in the row vector is the same as the number of columns in the matrix. Is there any predefined function for doing the following operation?

```
for c = 1 : columns(x)
    for r = 1 : rows(x)
        x(r, c) -= v(c);
    end
end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
bsxfun(@minus,x,v)
```

Here's an octave demonstration:

```
octave>  x = [1 2 3;2 3 4]
x =

   1   2   3
   2   3   4

octave> v = [2 0 1]
v =

   2   0   1

octave> 
octave> z=bsxfun(@minus,x,v)
z =

  -1   2   2
   0   3   3
```

Comment: Edited: misread dimensions of the row vector.  This now matches the question.

Comment: Hi! Do you know that in version 3.6.0 Octave introduced automatic broadcasting so you don't have to use `bsxfun` anymore?

Comment: @carandraug I didn't know that... very cool.  I typically use MATLAB, unless I'm away from a computer with it an need the online octave utility.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Octave 3.6.0 or later, you don't have to use `bsxfun` since Octave performs automatic [broadcasting](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Broadcasting.html#Broadcasting) (note that this is the same as actually using `bsxfun`, just easier on the eye). For example:

```
octave>  x = [1 2 3; 2 3 4]
x =

   1   2   3
   2   3   4

octave> v = [2 0 1]
v =

   2   0   1

octave> z = x - v
z =

  -1   2   2
   0   3   3
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can replicate your vector and directly subtract it from the matrix

```
z = x-repmat(v, size(x, 1), 1);
```